# ASP.Net MVC-5/EF-6 sln works in Visual Studio 2015, fails in VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have an MVC-5/EF-6 ASP.Net project/sln that builds without error and runs correctly in Visual Studio 2015. When I build the solution in Visual Studio 2017, I get the following error message:

Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
Nissan  D:\home\Nissan\Website\Nissan\EnitityModel\Nissan.edmx

Also, the project fails to run, and the edmx viewer cannot open.
From NuGet, the project uses (among other things):
    Package                              Installed Version   Latest Version
   EntityFramework                          v6.2.0-beta1      v6.2.0-beta1
   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess                 v12.1.24160719    v12.2.2.1100
   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework v12.1.2400        v12.2.2.1100

All NuGet packages are up-to-date except the 2 Oracle.ManagedDataAccess packages. If I update them, project still builds and runs using VS 2015, but I can no longer view the edmx file ("Cannot load Nissan.edmx: Exception has been thrown..."). Any idea what is keeping my project from building in VS 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install 
Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017.
Link download here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017.